# How to get through the 120 bytes limit?

Tags: c++, c

This is actually a SPOJ problem: [WAYS](https://www.spoj.pl/problems/WAYS/)

Now this is a very easy task what we need to do is to compute the [Central binomial coefficients.](http://oeis.org/A000984)

However the problem setter includes a very notorious source limit of 120 bytes, so my question is how to get past that source code limit in the languages that are allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming, that `C(2n,n) = (2n)!/(n!)^2 = (2n(2n-1)/n^2) * C(2(n-1),n-1) = ((4n-2)/n)*C(2(n-1),n-1)` here is function, which calculates central binomial:

```
int f(int n)
{
    return n==1? 2 : f(n-1)*(4*n-2)/n;
}
```

Edit: Here is probably shortest code:

```
int f(int n){return n<2?2:f(n-1)*(4*n-2)/n;}
```

It is only 44 characters.

Comment: @grep this code contains less than 120 characters. That's all I need.

Comment: My accepted solution is about 101 bytes,however the core computation can be optimized much further.

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan:`f(n){return n<2?2:f(n-1)*(4*n-2)/n;}` will do the work in SPOJ.However you can still shorten...

Comment: @grep Have a look to my edit. I make my code only 45 characters.

Comment: @Philando  right, I changed `==` to `<` Now only 44 characters ;)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried writing the code, but since the value of m is only 14, you could submit a table. Not sure if the code can be made shorter than this.

Comment: I have tried table using almost all shortening possible except the compression of the table but not getting through the source code limit.

Comment: What language are you using? Perhaps you can paste the code you have at hand.

Comment: I tried it using C,sorry I didn't saved it but it's just plain using arrays and usual shortening trick.